# How can I message a group of 50 all at once?

Tags: text, group

My iPhone 5s will only allow me to text up to 9 people. It is frustrating to have to text the same text over and over again. I'd like to text them all at the same time.

Comment: To send text messages to more than 9 people, I believe you would need a dedicated group message app.  What have you found from looking into those, any of them work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use GroupText! for iOS https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/group-text!/id377826584?mt=8